# PHP breaks after displaying date/time returned from SQL query

Tags: php

I am pulling several values from a sql query (see below) everything works great until i try to display the LastMessageTime (date/time) on the page.  When i try to display LastMessageTime on the page, the page does not render anything after that or the LastMessageTime for that matter.  i pulled the value directly through a sql query and get this 2013-03-15 17:32:10.000.  I am not sure if i need to escape something or if something else is missing

```
$sql = "SELECT Name, DNSName, LastMessageTime, IDENumber, Version FROM Computers where Name = '$assetname'";

echo "<table border=1 bordercolor=#FFCC00 style=background-color:#FFFFCC width=100%  cellpadding=3 cellspacing=5>";

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><b>Information</b></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<p style=font-family:verdana,arial,sans-serif;font-size:10px;</p>";
echo "</table>";
echo "<table border =1 width=100% cellpadding=3 cellspacing=5>";
echo "<td> Installed</td>";
echo "<td>".$SAVI2."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td> Version</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Version']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td> IDE Number</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['IDENumber']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td> Last Report time</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['LastMessageTime']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

$vard = $row['LastMessageTime'];
echo var_dump($vard);

RETURNED on page
object(DateTime)#1 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2013-03-15 16:47:52" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(14) "America/Denver" }

$sql = "SELECT Name, DomainName, OperatingSystem, ServicePack, IPAddressText, DNSName, SAVInstalled, LastLoggedOnUser, SAVVersion, IDENumber, SAVOnAccess, LastMessageTime FROM Computers where Name = '$assetname'";

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );

// Check for 0 results

if( $stmt === false) {
die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}



while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {




echo "<table border=1 bordercolor=#FFCC00 style=background-color:#FFFFCC width=100% cellpadding=3 cellspacing=5>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><b>Information</b></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<p style=font-family:verdana,arial,sans-serif;font-size:10px;</p>";
echo "</table>";
echo "<table border =1 width=100% cellpadding=3 cellspacing=5>";
echo "<td> Installed</td>";
echo "<td>".$SAVI2."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td> Version</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['SAVVersion']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td> IDE Number</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['IDENumber']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>last date</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['LastMessageTime']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";

echo "</table>";
$vard = $row['LastMessageTime'];
echo var_dump($vard);

}

/* Close the connection. */
sqlsrv_close( $conn); 

?>
```

Comment: How does the page source look like?

Comment: Where is `$row` declared? We need complete source code.

Comment: what does `var_dump($row);` output?

Comment: That was a great idea... thx  Here is what was returned object(DateTime)#1 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2013-03-15 16:47:52" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(14) "America/Denver" }

Comment: You still don't show how `$row` is defined.

Comment: The full code is quite large..  i will upload the php code

Comment: I am sorry, maybe i am not understanding.  I am pulling the value from the SQL query.  Just like all the other values that i am using in my code.  Do i need to define the $row - LastMessageTime

Comment: Did that help make sense of this at all?  thx

Answer (score 3):

In the line before the last line you are missing a ; at the end of line. Turn PHP errors on.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo on my part when i was posting.

Answer (score 0):

If `$vard = $row['LastMessageTime']; echo var_dump($vard);` returned:

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
    ["date"]=> string(19) "2013-03-15 16:47:52"
    ["timezone_type"]=> int(3)
    ["timezone"]=> string(14) "America/Denver"
}
```

Then this should work to output the last message time:

```
echo $row['LastMessageTime']->date;
```